# Searching for pairs of bash commands to turn off/on power intensive resources

Tags: command-line, bash, power-management

I am looking for pairs of bash commands to turn off and on power-intensive resources **without requiring a reboot or impacting a background program's ability to listen to the keyboard and get the current system time**.

Pairs I found so far include:

- `xrandr --output eDP-1 --off` and `xrandr --output eDP-1 --auto` to turn off and on my laptops primary monitor.
- `sudo service gdm3 stop` and `gdm3` to turn off and on Gnome.
- `sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager stop` and `sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager start` to stop and start the network manager.

Are there further pairs I am missing that help to save significant amounts of power whilst fulfilling the above requirements?

I have created a list of power-consuming processes and devices (measured when gnome is active, but no programs but the terminal are opened) using powertop, which look like this, showing which resources would be especially interesting to power off:

```
Power est.              Usage       Events/s    Category       Description
  6.66 W      0,0 pkts/s                Device         nic:virbr0
  746 mW    149,6 pkts/s                Device         Network interface: wlp2s0 (iwlwifi)
  429 mW     46,0%                      Device         Display backlight
  131 mW    100,8 ms/s      91,0        Process        [PID 26107] /usr/bin/gnome-shell
  118 mW      0,0 pkts/s                Device         Network interface: enp0s31f6 (e1000e)
 34.0 mW     26,4 ms/s      48,1        Process        [PID 28173] /usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server
 33.3 mW     18,7 ms/s      54,6        Process        [PID 4733] /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose
 29.8 mW     44,6 ms/s       8,2        kWork          intel_atomic_commit_work
 11.6 mW     17,3 ms/s      36,5        Interrupt      [9] acpi
 10.2 mW     15,3 ms/s      0,15        Process        [PID 22174] gnome-system-mo
 8.65 mW     12,9 ms/s      14,0        Process        [PID 5078] indicator-multiload
 7.68 mW     11,5 ms/s      37,7        Process        [PID 5149] megasync
 5.18 mW      7,8 ms/s      15,3        Interrupt      [7] sched(softirq)
 4.82 mW    696,6 µs/s      19,6        Process        [PID 1] /sbin/init splash
 4.65 mW      7,0 ms/s     191,9        Timer          tick_sched_timer
 4.10 mW      6,1 ms/s       0,5        Process        [PID 5107] psensor
 3.86 mW      5,0 ms/s      47,5        Process        [PID 22614] [irq/127-iwlwifi]
 3.41 mW      5,1 ms/s       9,3        Process        [PID 29324] /usr/bin/gnome-shell
 2.71 mW      4,0 ms/s      22,3        Process        [PID 1685] /usr/sbin/iio-sensor-proxy
 2.16 mW      3,2 ms/s       0,4        Process        [PID 4741] /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --session --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
 2.06 mW      3,1 ms/s      15,7        Timer          hrtimer_wakeup
 1.91 mW      2,9 ms/s       3,1        Process        [PID 690] /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
 1.79 mW      2,7 ms/s       6,2        Interrupt      [122] xhci_hcd
 1.76 mW      2,6 ms/s      29,9        kWork          retire_work_handler
 1.43 mW      2,1 ms/s       2,0        Process        [PID 3032] powertop --calibrate
 1.32 mW      2,0 ms/s      0,10        Interrupt      [9] RCU(softirq)
 1.28 mW      1,9 ms/s      0,05        Interrupt      [1] timer(softirq)
 1.23 mW      1,8 ms/s       4,5        Interrupt      [126] i915
 1.17 mW      1,2 ms/s       1,0        Process        [PID 5080] nautilus-desktop
 1.07 mW      1,2 ms/s       1,4        Process        [PID 5743] gjs /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/zorin-connect@zorinos.com/service/daemon.js
 1.02 mW    373,3 µs/s       1,5        Process        [PID 4841] /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi2-registryd --use-gnome-session
 822 µW       1,2 ms/s      0,00        Timer          process_timeout
 819 µW       1,2 ms/s       0,5        kWork          delayed_fput
 755 µW       1,1 ms/s      34,0        Interrupt      [127] iwlwifi
 738 µW       1,1 ms/s      0,00        Process        [PID 25977] [kworker/u8:0]
 709 µW       1,1 ms/s      0,15        kWork          wb_workfn
 596 µW       0,9 ms/s       0,6        Process        [PID 4891] ibus-daemon --xim --panel disable
 561 µW       0,8 ms/s      22,4        Interrupt      [0] HI_SOFTIRQ
 535 µW       0,8 ms/s      0,00        Process        [PID 29401] [kworker/u8:4]
 519 µW       0,8 ms/s       0,7        Process        [PID 4893] ibus-daemon --xim --panel disable
 507 µW     312,9 µs/s       1,0        Process        [PID 22655] /snap/signal-desktop/311/opt/Signal/signal-desktop --use-tray-icon --no-sandbox --no-sandbox
 485 µW       0,7 ms/s      30,1        Process        [PID 11] [rcu_sched]
 447 µW     669,4 µs/s      0,05        Process        [PID 22375] tlp
 414 µW     620,1 µs/s       1,1        Process        [PID 22862] /snap/signal-desktop/311/opt/Signal/signal-desktop --type=renderer --no-sandbox --field-trial-handle=86637332313649
 398 µW     149,1 µs/s       0,6        Process        [PID 6078] /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/caffeine
 367 µW     103,7 µs/s       0,8        Process        [PID 4975] /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-clipboard
 350 µW     523,2 µs/s       0,4        Process        [PID 4976] /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-color
 340 µW     509,5 µs/s      0,00        Process        [PID 26027] [kworker/u8:3]
 331 µW     494,8 µs/s      0,00        Process        [PID 1863] /usr/bin/gnome-shell
 303 µW     453,2 µs/s       1,1        Process        [PID 1723] /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
 300 µW     449,3 µs/s       0,4        Process        [PID 6076] /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/indicator-cpufreq
 299 µW     447,0 µs/s       2,0        Process        [PID 1721] /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
 291 µW     436,2 µs/s      0,00        Timer          delayed_work_timer_fn
```

Please note that this question is not a duplicate of similar power saving questions asked here since most other questions concerning power-saving allow answers requiring a reboot whilst not allowing answers impacting the user's ability to work on the laptop whilst power is saved.